# Angular - When receiving @Input, how to wait for other async data in the children component before executing the @Input logic

Tags: angular, async-await, rxjs

**PROBLEM INTRODUCTION**

I have **button-address** child component which **onInit** loads a list of mapItems:

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.refreshDataList();
    }

    protected refreshDataList(): void {
        this.subscription = this.getDataList()
            .pipe(
                switchMap((result: AddressModel[]) => {
                    this.dataSource.data = [...result].map((d) => {
                        return {
                            address: d,
                            selected: this.selectedItems
                                ? this.selectedItems.some(
                                      (it) =>
                                          it.address.pointName ===
                                              d.pointName && it.selected
                                  )
                                : false,
                        };
                    });
                    this.sortList(this.dataSource.data);

                    return this.preSelectUserPreferencesPOIs();
                })
            )
            .subscribe();
    }

    protected getDataList(): Observable<AddressModel[]> {
        return this.store.pipe(select(selectZoi));
    }
```

The value of **this.dataSource.data** is set inside the **switchMap()** operator. This value is important because later the user will select elements from the list. So I will listen for the click events from the user, find the right element of **this.dataSource.data** and update the selected item.

My issue is that when the app inits, I also receive an **@Input** from another stream whose aim is to programatically select the appropiate item in the list of **this.dataSource.data**:

```
    @Input()
    set proximityReportPoiZoi(poiZoi: ProximityReportPoiZoi) {
        this.toggleSelectedPoiZoi(poiZoi.id);
    }

    protected toggleSelectedPoiZoi(poiZoiId: string) {
        const addressZoneSelectionModel = this.dataSource.data.find(
            (item) => poiZoiId === item.address.id
        );
        const address = addressZoneSelectionModel.address;
        if (addressZoneSelectionModel.selected) {
            addressZoneSelectionModel.selected = false;
            this.showHidePoiZoi(address, false);
        } else {
            addressZoneSelectionModel.selected = true;
            this.showHidePoiZoi(address, true);
        }
    }
```

**THE BUGGY LINE**

However, because the request to the **store** takes some time, when the **@Input** (which by the way is also an observable) is received by the component, the code inside **toggleSelectedPoiZoi()** cannot find the appropiate item as **this.dataSource.data** is still empty:

```
        const addressZoneSelectionModel = this.dataSource.data.find(
            (item) => poiZoiId === item.address.id
        );
```

**THE QUESTION**

How can I make my **@Input()** wait for the component to load the data for **this.dataSource.data** before executing **this.toggleSelectedPoiZoi()**?
This issue only happens during the app init.

**THINGS I HAVE TRIED**

1. **Await** for the observable to load the data

```
    @Input()
    set proximityReportPoiZoi(poiZoi: ProximityReportPoiZoi) {
            const updatePoiZoiSeletion = async () => {
                await this.refreshDataList().toPromise();
                this.toggleSelectedPoiZoi(poiZoi.id);
            }
            updatePoiZoiSeletion();
    }
```

But it never gets to execute the following line with **this.toggleSelectedPoiZoi()** method. If I change *.toPromise()* for *.subscribe()*, the value of **this.dataSource.data** is still an empty array so no item can be selected.

2. **ngOnChanges**

However no success as although I can listen for the changes on the value of the **@Input**, I cannot listen for changes in **this.dataSource.data**.

3. Get the value of the **@Input()** by subscribing it at a later stage in the parent component, in **ngAfterViewInit()** cycle.

Angular complains that because the *@Input* is passed through the template, the value of **proximityReportPoiZoi$** property has changed after parent component initialization. See the parent template:

```
        <app-button-address 
            [proximityReportPoiZoi]="(proximityReportPoiZoi$ | async)"
        ></app-button-address>
```

Any help is highly appreciated beforehand :)

Answer (score 0):

Accd. to Angular life-cycle hooks event sequence, `ngOnChanges` would be triggered before `ngOnInit`. But calling the entire subscription in the `ngOnChanges` might lead to performance issues since from [docs](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence):

> Note that this happens very frequently, so any operation you perform here impacts performance significantly.

So what you could do is use the `@Input` variable inside the `ngOnInit` directly in the subscription.

```js
export someComponent implements OnInit {
  _poiZoi: ProximityReportPoiZoi;

  @Input()
  set proximityReportPoiZoi(poiZoi: ProximityReportPoiZoi) {
    this._poiZoi = poiZoi;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.refreshDataList();
  }

  protected refreshDataList(): void {
    this.subscription = this.getDataList().pipe(
      switchMap((result: AddressModel[]) => {
        this.dataSource.data = [...result].map((d) => {
          return {
            address: d,
            selected: this.selectedItems 
              ? this.selectedItems.some((it) =>
                  it.address.pointName === d.pointName && it.selected
                ) 
              : false,
          };
        });
        this.sortList(this.dataSource.data);
        this.preSelectUserPreferencesPOIs();
      }),
      map(() => this._poiZoi.id)
    )
    .subscribe({
      next: (poiZoiId: any) => this.toggleSelectedPoiZoi(poiZoi.id),
      error: (error: any) => console.log(error)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue I see is that you rely on `this._poiZoi`  value to be defined when we reach the subscription. However, it might be that because of the second stream that manages the **proximityReportPoiZoi** the *@Input* changes later on and this is not catched in the code. That's why I mention that my problem is only on Angular Startup.

Comment: @Santironhacker: In that case you could try an approach using RxJS observables as proposed by Picci.

Answer (score 0):

I propose an approach based on pure RxJs logic which does not relay on the Angular lifecycle methods.

If I understand right, you have 2 streams at play

- the stream whose source is `this.getDataList()` and whose notification is used to set `this.dataSource.data` - let's call this stream **obs_1**
- the stream that emits the value which is passed to the `proximityReportPoiZoi` Input and which is used to select the the initial value of the list of values - let's call this stream **obs_2**

The problem here is to make sure that we do the following steps in strict temporal order

- receive the notification from **obs_2**
- `subscribe` to **obs_1** and process its notification
- process the notification of **obs_2** after the notification of **obs_1** has been processed.

In terms of pure rxJs logic, this is a good case for using `concatMap`.

The logic could look like this

```
obs_2.pipe(
  concatMap(res_2 => obs_1.pipe(
      map(res_1 => ([res_1, res_2))
    )
  )
).subscribe(
  ([addressModelArray, poiZoi]) => {
     setDataSourceData(addressModelArray) // i.e. the logic in switchMap
     toggleSelectedPoiZoi(poiZoi.id);
  }
)
```

You can try to implement this approach within your `button-address` Component. This could be accomplished implementing **obs_2** as a `Subject` which emits within the `proximityReportPoiZoi` set method.

The approach I would use though is to try to isolate all this logic into a `service` which is injected into the `button-address` Component. This `service` knows both **obs_1** and **obs_2** and therefore can implement this logic in the `pipe` and expose it as a public API Observable, something like this

```
public listAndSelectedVal$ = obs_2.pipe(
  concatMap(res_2 => obs_1.pipe(
      // apply some logic to filter the default value
      filter(res_1 => res_1.length > 0),
      map(res_1 => ([res_1, res_2))
    )
  )
)
```

`button-address` Component would need to subscribe tp `listAndSelectedVal$` to perform its job.

It is possible also to explore the use of `combineLatest` in case **obs_1** and **obs_2** can emit more than once before completing.

Such an approach would make testing much easier, since testing a service is simpler than testing a Component.

Comment: Thanks Picci. Your approach has allowed me to move one step further.
I realize that replicating your code, inside the **subscribe([addressModelArray, poiZoi])**, actually the value returned by the method `getDataList()` is an empty string from the Angular store. So actually I need to update my logic to wait for **addressModelArray** to be filled with data. I will check the answer from the store and update you further.

Comment: If the store is an NgRx store, I would expect that `getDataList()` emits any time the underlying state changes. If you get an empty string is probably because this is the initial state. If this is the case, then a filter could do the trick. Look at my updated answer.